# Firestore Many to Many Relationships

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Would like suggestions related to a many to many structure with roles/permissions.

We need a structure that permits users to belong to many organizations and users have a role/permissions for each organization.  For example, `User1` belongs to `ABC CO` as `Admin`, and `User1` belongs to `XYZ CO` as `Guest`

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this issue as follows:

```
organizations (collection) {
    ABC (doc) {
        permissions (object): {
            User1DocID (object): {
                admin: true
            }
        }
    }
    XYZ (doc) {
        permissions (object): {
            User2DocID (object): {
                guest: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can configure the rules like this:

```
match /origanizations/{origanization} {
    allow update, read: if resource.data.permissions[request.auth.uid].admin == true;
    allow read: if resource.data.permissions[request.auth.uid].guest == true;
}
```

For the resources of the organization you would have to store the Organization ID in the specific docs (obviously). Then you can setup the rules for them as follows:

```
match /origanizationRessources/{origanizationRessource} {
    allow update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/$(resource.data.organizationId)).data.permissions[request.auth.uid].admin == true;
}
```

You can also easily query for data that the user has specific permissions on with this design.

Please note: This design fits our purposes as we have a finite, straightforward number of users assigned to the organizations. If you are unsure, have a look at the limits in terms of document sizes (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) to find out whether you have to rely on another design. If you happen to be in the position of potentially hitting those limits, consider a seperate mapping collection.